# Setting up different number of users in JMeter master slave

Tags: jmeter, master-slave

In my JMeter master-slave setup, I want to setup a different number of users in each slave for the same thread group.Is it possible to setup with properties file? Is there any other way?

In Load Runner we can configure this easily with Load Generators. How to do in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing it as follows:

1. In your Test Script define number of users using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like `${__P(users,)}`

   [image: Users via property]
2. In *user.properties* file on each slave machine specify the desired number of users like:

   ```
   users=50
   ```

   You can also pass the value via `-J` argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jusers=100 ...
   ```

References:

- [How to do remote testing the 'proper way'?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)